# Download multiple files on tap of RecylerView item and show download progress

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am in problem right now. There are multiple downloadable items in `RecyclerView`. On tap of each item, file starts downloading in separate threads. I have to show download progress w.r.t each card in the same `RecyclerView` and while I navigate to another page and come back, download progress will be continue to show. Can you please help me out?

Comment: hey amit try https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/PRDownloader library. it provide OnProgressListenerupdate listener.

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't return which file has been downloaded/running in listner. Thats why when i add    request and at the same time update ui in recyclerview with the progress update all progress will gets overlapped with another upon recyclerview scrolling

Comment: Also it only returns only downloadid which can be monitored later with status of downloading or not. Their are no way to track dowbload progress against that download id when you close app and reopen it.

Comment: you can get the download status using the download ID in recyclerview so you can display that progress in your custom progressbar.

Comment: But download status returns only downloading or not. How will i get progress. For single download it is very much easy but i am facing problem in displaying them with multiple download. Can you please post any code snippet then it will very helpful